# Auto Increment userdefined id

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2005

Hi can anyone give me an idea how to create an auto generated id like ED01,ED02 etc., so that when i am entering data the id should be automatically incremented

Comment: Why not just use a primary key field which auto-increments and then a prefix field if necessary? When you do the output, just combine the two to get `ED01`, `ED02`, etc.

Comment: After ED99 i will display ED100

Comment: Do you require values < 100 to be padded with zero's?

Comment: And another important question: are gaps in the numbers allowed? If not, then IDENTITY is not a solution and you'll have to implement something using triggers or on the client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguably this would be better done on the client side but you could

- create a normal [identity column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196(SQL.80).aspx)
- add a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx) doing the formatting.

**Test script**

```
DECLARE @ED TABLE (
  ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1)
  , UserID AS 'ED' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(32))
  , I INTEGER
)

DECLARE @I INTEGER
SET @I = 0
WHILE @I < 100
BEGIN
  SET @I = @I + 1
  INSERT INTO @ED VALUES (@I)
END

SELECT * FROM @ED
```